# should these tags 'hashkafa' and 'hashkafah-philosophy' be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

These two tags seem to be the same thing, should they be merged, or one deleted?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hashkafa

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hashkafah-philosophy

Answer (score 1):

Both of those links appear to produce the same set of results, which are tagged hashkafah-philosophy.  Are they synonyms?

I don't see the point of a synonym that is a substring of the target tag, so I vote to remove hashkafa.

Comment: Sorry; I merged them but failed to report that here initially. I see your point about substrings and may perhaps just merge without synonymizing in this sort of case in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I've merged them. Thanks.

(I did this before Monica posted her answer but forgot to click "Post" on this answer at the time.)